# Android hash-key is causing issues with Facebook and Google authentication in Ionic app

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, ionic4, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm not sure where my issues began but I think it was when I added additional emulators or SDKs in Android studio but at one point Google and Facebook authentication was working for both iOS and Android.  Now it no longer works for Android.  Facebook authentication gives me a "login error there is an error in logging you into this application". Google gives me an "Error 10 Cannot read property 'idToken' of undefined".  I've tried removing both apps from Firebase and my app then re-adding to no avail.

Here's how I'm generating my hash-key:
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

If I navigate to that directory i can see debug.keystore.

Here's the code but the code isn't really the issue because this use to work.

```js
    return this.facebook.login(['email'])
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('facebook login', error);
      });
```

and Google

```js
      console.log('before gPlus');
      return this.googlePlus.login({
        webClientId : environment.googleWebClientId,
        offline : true,
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
```

I'm using the Web client (auto-created by Google Service) as the clientId...so there has to be something going wrong with my hash-key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I've been stuck on this for weeks now.

Comment: which version of which plugins are you using for the auth?

Comment: "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.3.0",